# Vscode , wrong error messages

Tags: solidity

if some one could help me how to disable wrong warning errors in vscode ?

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with Ethereum?

Comment: As long as the contracts compile, there's no problem.

Comment: hello @user16217248 , i just create a new contract , i'm learning solidity now

Comment: hello @ZartajAfser the problem is fixed , i reinstall vscode after install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity extinction

Comment: Yup, that's what I said. VS code sometimes shows unnecessary errors. The best way is to check if the contracts are compiling or not.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed , reinstall vscode with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity extinction ,